# Stargazer does not output a Table in PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

Why does my Stargazer function not output a table? It only outputs some texts when I make a PDF. Here is an example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r cars}
stargazer::stargazer(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: By the way my code is inside a Function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `results='asis'` in the header. ALso `header=FALSE` suppresses the `% Table created by stargazer` header.

As explained in the [RMarkdown guidance](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html):

> Note the use of the results='asis' chunk option. This is required to ensure that the raw table output isn’t processed further by knitr.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r mtcars, results='asis'}
stargazer::stargazer(mtcars,  header=FALSE, type='latex')
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi why is there an unexpected token in the first line? ```{r df2, results='asis'}

Comment: Unexpected token? Do you mean `mtcars`? That is the chunk name. http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html