# Stargazer Table in Latex Format - R

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I Imagine this pretty simple, but I am very new to R and stargazer so I am not sure how to do this.

I have a code block (seen below):

```
ses <- diag(vcovHC(model))
stargazer(model,
          type='latex',
          header = F,
          se = ses,
          title="")
```

I want to convert this output into a Latex Table. I've tried playing with markdown but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Can anyone advise on how to do this? I've tried using latex editors but I can't source the data into that.

Thank you!

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026824/stargazer-does-not-output-a-table-in-pdf and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670299/using-stargazer-with-rstudio-and-knitr

Answer (score 1):

Output is text file with latex code. You can use it in latex editor with appropriate modifications.
Hope I have answered your query correctly.

```
sink("output.txt")
stargazer(mod1,se = robustse_mod_1,type = "latex")
sink()
```